# Civicrm profile field values using same record type goes missing/overwritten

Tags: civicontribute, profile, civireport

I have created a CiviContribute profile with multiple **postal code** fields of record type **contact**. All these profile fields have different labels and sub-type. But when a user makes a contribution, only postal code value of **last field** is being **stored** in the database and the postal code **values of first 2 fields** goes **missing/overwritten**. Any help would be much appreciated.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Please try to replicate this issue on a demo site at http://demo.civicrm.org.  If you can, I would file a bug at issues.civicrm.org.  Note that filing a bug doesn't get it fixed; if this is important to you, consider writing a patch if you know how, or submitting this to the Paid Issue Queue (https://civicrm.org/paid-issue-queue)

Comment: I could not replicate this issue on a demo site dmaster.demo.civicrm.org. But I noticed an another issue. I have created a test profile https://goo.gl/YnD6La and test contribution page https://goo.gl/9B7dAp . Did 2 contributions and pulled out a contribution report. I found that all 3 postal code field values of previous contribution were overwritten by a new contribution. Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: What version of CiviCRM are you using?  it could be you've found a bug that's already been fixed.

Comment: I am using the latest version of CiviCRM i.e 4.7.14. The demo site http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org have the version 4.7.16. But the overwriting issue is still happening on this version as well.